# Android: OnClickEvent on disabled Spinner

Tags: android, overlay, spinner

I have a disabled Spinner and want it to enable and open the selection menu when I touch/click it - is there any way to do this?

I thought about an invisible overlay of some kind so I could catch OnClickEvents, but I don't know if Android supports this.

Regards,
jellyfish

Edit: It's pretty much similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403343/enable-a-currently-disabled-spinner-in-android), but I encountered some difficulties when the selection of one Spinner already shows what the user wants. (see comments)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, why have it disabled if you want to open it on touch/click. Surely this would be achieved by just not disabling it?

Comment: Uhm, it's due to a three-Spinner-structure I discribed in my last question. Basically, the selection made in one Spinner will change the content of the next one and so on.

Comment: So what I wanted the three to look like when the activity starts is "Enabled - Disabled - Disabled". If I now make a selection in 1, then 2 get's enabled and so on.

However, if 1 already shows the selection the user wants, there is no need in opening 1. Even worse, he would have to change to another item, then select the one he wants again, as otherwise there seems to be no "OnItemSelectEvent". So I'd rather imagined the user to click upon the disabled Spinner 2 and open it while leaving 3 still disabled.

Comment: If it's to complicated I might just leave them all three enabled. But then I have to adjust them all the time to the selections, in which I kind of struggle as well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a step back and rethink your strategy.  I get what you're trying to do and I can appreciate minimizing the number of user interactions to get the desired result.  If you're populating Spinner1 with some value be it the default or from a user saved state then you should consider populating Spinner2 and Spinner3 based on those same assumptions.

You can also leave the Spinner2 active, but empty until it is clicked.  It can read the state of Spinner1 to populate itself when it's needed.

Another thing you could do is present Spinner1 with a default or user value.  Leave Spinner2 active, but populate it on click and Spinner3 is not activated until Spinner2 has a selection.

All just suggestions.  Sometimes fresh ideas help.

No matter what you decide it will have to be intuitive to the user.  Good luck!

Comment: Sounds good to me, thank you! :) How is leaving the Spinner empty done?

Comment: Anything you put into the view XML will be on the screen.  And it's empty by default.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I have to ask again... "You can also leave the Spinner2 active, but empty until it is clicked." - IS there a way to determine it was clicked? All I found is that OnClickEvent isn't supported... (or is this already a new question? ^^)