# Spinner disable is not working

Tags: android

I tried to disable the spinner control, but its not working. I have given `spinnerControl.setEnable(false);` this code disable spinner process but, it will not put spinner in gray color(ie) disabled manner.

Comment: why don't u try spinner.setVisibility(View.Gone); may be this ll serve the purpose too..

Comment: No, i want only spinner control to get gray color. spinner should visible all the time.

Comment: well tats working fine for me.. its getting disabled but color is not changing.. post part of your code.. so tat v can figure out wats the problemm

Answer (score 0):

[Enable a currently disabled Spinner in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403343/enable-a-currently-disabled-spinner-in-android)

Read the answer of this given above link may be it is help full to you.

Comment: My spinner is working fine . i just want to disable the spinner control like putting spinner in gray color.